# return folder path illustrator jsx different result in illustrat CC2018 to 2021

Tags: javascript, jsx, adobe-illustrator

I have a couple of long-standing scripts that have worked well over the last few years. However when I run the script in newer versions of (illustrator 2019 onward) the exact same piece of code returns differing results, which is causing the script to fail. This is the code that's causing the issues:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;//Gets the active document
var fileName = doc.name.slice(0, 9);//Gets the G Number
$.writeln('thisfile ', fileName)
var numArtboards = doc.artboards.length;//returns the number of artboards in the document
var folderPath = (doc.fullName.parent.fsName.replace(/\\/g, '/'))
$.writeln('folderPath ', folderPath)
```

In illustrator CC 2018 the output console returns the following:

```
thisfile G0037_21X
folderPath /Users/bobhaslett/Documents/MF1/2021/01 January 2021/13:01:2021
```

This is what I expect and works with the rest of the script. However, if I try to run this same code using Illustrator 2021 get the following error:

```
Starting /Users/bobhaslett/Documents/MF1/2021/01 January 2021/13:01:2021/ExportArtboards/ExportArtboards v0.1.4.jsx in target: illustrator-25.064 and engine: main.
Runtime Error: Error Code# 21: null is not an object @ file '~/Documents/MF1/2021/01%20January%202021/13:01:2021/ExportArtboards/ExportArtboards%20v0.1.4.jsx' [line:7, col:1]
```

I really stuck here and would appreciate any help

Thanks

Here is the full script as requested

```
//Version 0.1.4

var doc = app.activeDocument;//Gets the active document
var fileName = doc.name.slice(0, 9);//Gets the G Number
$.writeln('thisfile ', fileName)
var numArtboards = doc.artboards.length;//returns the number of artboards in the document
var folderPath = (doc.fullName.parent.fsName.replace(/\\/g, '/'))
$.writeln('folderPath ', folderPath)
//var folderPath = (app.activeDocument.fullName.parent.fsName).toString().replace(/\\/g, '/');
var options = new ImageCaptureOptions();
var filePath = folderPath + "/ImageSet";
$.writeln(filePath)
var folder = new Folder(filePath);
if (!folder.exists) {
    folder.create()
}

//Loop through every item on the page checking for text frames
for (var i = 0; i < doc.pageItems.length; i++) {
    var item = doc.pageItems[i];
    if (item.constructor.name == "TextFrame") {
        try {
            checkText(item);
        }
        catch (e) { }
    }
}
//Checks text for smart puctuation
function checkText(item) {
    //var txt = item.contents.replace("“", "‘");
    var txt = item.contents.replace(/n't/g, "n’t")
    item.contents = txt;
    var txt = item.contents.replace(/'r/g, "’r")
    item.contents = txt;
    var txt = item.contents.replace(/'d/g, "’d")
    item.contents = txt;
    var txt = item.contents.replace(/'l/g, "’l")
    item.contents = txt;
    var txt = item.contents.replace(/'s/g, "’s")
    item.contents = txt;
    var txt = item.contents.replace(/'m/g, "’m")
    item.contents = txt;
    var txt = item.contents.replace(/s'/g, "s’")
    item.contents = txt;
}


for (var i = 0; i < numArtboards; i++) {
    doc.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(i);
    var activeAB = doc.artboards[doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex()];

    options.artBoardClipping = true;
    options.resolution = 150;
    options.antiAliasing = true;
    options.matte = false;
    options.horizontalScale = 100;
    options.verticalScale = 100;
    options.transparency = true;

    var artboardName = doc.artboards[i].name;
    var destFile = new File(filePath + "/" + fileName + " " + artboardName + ".png");
    doc.imageCapture(destFile, activeAB.artboardRect, options);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it gets stranger. the script works fully on my PowerBook running version 24.3 and on my colleague's PowerBook running 25.0. But not on my iMac running 25.0

Comment: the full code is working as expected on my windows 10 running Ai 25.0.1. if I have to guess I'd say that the error is specific to your system leading me to assume it has to do with permissions or something similar. maybe run Ai as admin or try another directory?

Comment: I’m coming to a similar conclusion. it seems to run OK when I save the file in google drive. I’m pretty sure that the ai is already running in admin so looking at permissions